# Why are quantum states represented by Bloch or Q-Spheres?

Tags: quantum-state, state-space-geometry

I'm new to quantum computing.

Why are quantum states/qubits represented on spheres: either as Bloch spheres or as Q-Spheres.

Is it just a convenient graphical representation, or is there something deeper going on?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Quantum bits are mathematically represented by two complex numbers $\alpha$ and $\beta$, so we say the state of a qubit is $$|\psi\rangle=\pmatrix{\alpha\\ \beta}=\alpha|0\rangle+\beta|1\rangle\in\mathbb{C}^2$$ Since a complex number $z\in\mathbb{C}$ may be written as $z=a+bi$ where $a,b\in\mathbb{R}$, the qubit can be represented by four real numbers, also known as a [quaternion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternion). You might expect the state of a qubit then to be represented by any point in $\mathbb{R}^4$, however all valid states of a qubit are constrained by the fact that every state has unit norm: $\langle\psi|\psi\rangle=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2=1$. The set of operators that maintain unit norm on quaternions is the unitary group $U(2)$. However, we also don't care about a global phase, which corresponds to restricting the operators to the special unitary group $SU(2)$. It is [well known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_rotation_group#Connection_between_SO(3)_and_SU(2)) that $SU(2)$ is identified with the group of 3D rotations $SO(3)$, the symmetry group of a sphere. This is *why* we can represent qubit states on spheres.

While it *is* just a convenient way to represent the qubit state graphically, there is some interesting group symmetry that allows us to do it.

Comment: The well-known result that you linked does not say that $SU(2)$ is identified with $SO(3)$. It says that $SU(2)$ is the universal cover of $SO(3)$.

Comment: Forgive my loose terminology, Nick is correct. But the point remains.

Comment: Thank you Dylan!

Answer (score 1):

This is a special case of my answer [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/35267/what-mathematical-object-is-the-set-of-quantum-states-of-a-qudit-how-should-one/35268#35268) with $d = 2$, but I think it is worth elaborating. For the qubit Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^2$, the corresponding space of qubit states is the complex projective line $\mathbb{C}\textbf{P}^1$. The complex projective line is equivalently the [Riemann sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_sphere), and this is where the Bloch sphere picture comes from.

Comment: Thanks Nick
In the Qubit Hilbert space ℂ, does the  variable represent 'dimensions'?
And can you elaborate on why d = 2 in this particular instance?

Comment: A qudit has Hilbert space $\mathbb{C}^d$, where $d$ represents dimensions. So a qubit is a special case of a qudit where $d = 2$ because a qubit has two basis vectors $|0\rangle$ and $|1\rangle$. Geometrically, a qudit has state space $\mathbb{C}\textbf{P}^{d - 1}$. So a qubit has state space $\mathbb{C}\textbf{P}^{2 - 1} = \mathbb{C}\textbf{P}^{1}$, which just so happens to be a sphere.